# How to handle error while implementing grpc-java server?

Tags: grpc-java

gRPC newbie here, I am following "quickstart".

But I am not sure what is behavior of gprc-java when `my code` throw RuntimeException.

Would client get `Status#UNKNOWN`?

Comment: I will add sample code, soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `StreamObserver.onError(StatusRuntimeException)`, it will use the code from the exception.  If your exception does't extend StatusRuntimeException or StatusException, The code will be UNKNOWN, but the Status message will be the same as the exception's.